# Get distance from left edge of UITableView and UITableViewCell Text Label

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

How can I get the distance between the left edge of a UITableView (or View for that matter) and the start of the text in the UITableViewCell?  I need this to work on all devices from 4S on up through 6 Plus.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but `CGRectGetMinX(cell.textLabel.frame)` should do the trick, assuming the tableView is filling the view. textLabel's frame's origin.x will be the distance from the left edge o the main view.

Comment: @BartekChlebek might be a problem if the developer decides the text should be right aligned. In that case, the left edge of the text label frame doesn't necessarily corresponds to the left edge of the first character of the text string. Although, it doesn't seem like Neal is asking for that complicated of a scenario that I described, more closer to your suggestion.